# Logging in Maven Spring Web Project

Tags: spring, maven, log4j

I have a Maven Spring Web Project in which I intend to include log4j for logging purposes. I have included log4j in pom.xml as :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

In the resources folder is the `log4j.properties`.

In am using the `logger.debug` to generate the logs . But it is not getting generated. I am using jdk1.7.0_75. What can be the issue 
? Is there some dependency on jar files version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that a spring-boot project? because you need to exclude the logback dependency (which would be used if present as first choice) in that case

Comment: No it is not a spring-boot project